# SQL cumulative sum from alias

Tags: postgresql, alias, cumulative-sum

I want to do the cumulative sum from the percentage that I generated in the same query. I know the way to do the cumulative :

```
select sum(grandtotal)over(order by agentname) as cumulative from data
```

But now the column that I would like to do the cumulative is not in database yet. it is generated in the same query (alias : percentage)

```
 SELECT 
 agentname,weakness,
 count(*) as frequency,
 count(*)*100.00/sum(count(*))over(order by agentname) as percentage
 from ... where ...
```

and I try :

```
(select sum(percentage)over(order by agentname) as cumulative from data
```

It comes with error saying that 'percentage' column is not exist. How do I apply the cumulative sum? Thank you

This is the table looks like for the output I want:

```
    agentname | weakness | frequency | percentage | cumulative
       A      |   W1     |     4     |    36.36   |    36.36
       A      |   W2     |     4     |    36.36   |    72.72
       A      |   W3     |     2     |    18.18   |    90.09
       A      |   W4     |     1     |     9.09   |     100
```

Comment: Can you show us sample input and output data?

Comment: If fail to understand how this part of your query `sum(count(*))over(order by agentname)` executes without error.

Comment: @tim is the table enough?

Comment: @giorgios. no it's not. I will provide the image n full code

Comment: You still never showed us the expected output.  You don't want to leave people guessing here.

Comment: @tim. picture added. there will be an additional column of cumulative beside 'prc' column

Comment: And what is in this column?

Comment: @tim the additional column will be the cumulative sum of prc. 
16.66666667
33.33333333
45.83333333
54.16666667
62.5
70.83333333
79.16666667
87.5
95.83333333
100

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A window function cannot be calculated based on the results of another window function in the same `SELECT` (in most databases).

You have to nest that query once more:

```
SELECT t.*, SUM(percentage) OVER (ORDER BY agentname) AS cumulative
FROM (
  SELECT 
    agentname,
    weakness,
    COUNT(*) AS frequency,

    -- No ORDER BY in this SUM()!
    COUNT(*) * 100.00 / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER () AS percentage
  FROM ... WHERE ...
) AS t
ORDER BY agentname
```

#### Further feedback:

While you're at it, I suggest making the `ORDER BY` clauses deterministic by adding another column to them, e.g. `weakness`.

Also, I'm not sure about your requirements, but I would imagine that those percentages need to be calculated per `agentname`? In that case, you'd have to add an `PARTITION BY agentname` clause in your `SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER(...)` window function.

Comment: The code results no syntax error. But the cumulative result is error. It shows the same number for same frequency though the final sum is correct. I try to figure it out still

Comment: Got it. I resolve the problem from my other post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34428444/running-total-using-windows-function-in-sql-has-same-result-for-same-data/34428487#34428487. Thank you. the nested advice do help

Comment: @Elbert: Thanks for the link. I've learned something myself in that other question. Rather than depending on `ROWS` or `RANGE`, I would definitely make sure that your `ORDER BY` clause is deterministic. This is always a good idea, in SQL.