# running total using windows function in sql has same result for same data

Tags: postgresql, window-functions, cumulative-sum

From every references that I search how to do cumulative sum / running total. they said it's better using windows function, so I did

```
select grandtotal,sum(grandtotal)over(order by agentname) from call
```

but I realize that the results are okay as long as the value of each rows are different. Here is the result :

[image: result]

Is There anyway to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to review the documentation on window specifications (which is [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS)).  The default is "range between" which defines the range by the values in the row.  You want "rows between":

```
select grandtotal,
       sum(grandtotal) over (order by agentname rows between unbounded preceding and current row)
from call;
```

Alternatively, you could include an `id` column in the sort to guarantee uniqueness and not have to deal with the issue of equal key values.

Comment: This is badass ! Thank you very much

Comment: Interesting, I wasn't aware of this subtle difference between `ROWS` and `RANGE`. Often, users will use "deterministic" `ORDER BY` clauses (e.g. order by some unique key), in case of which both `ROWS` and `RANGE` will mean the same thing.